# button_id Cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: java, android, button, android-intent

I've been searching about this problem a lot before posting this question but still couldnt get any help,kindly help me in solving this error as im a newbie to this field..!!

## Main Java Code

```
package com.example.firstapp;

import com.example.firstapp.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Second.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

## activity_xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.firstapp.MainActivity" >

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="26dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberPassword" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="Enter your Password"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
      android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textEmailAddress" >

    <requestFocus android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

    </EditText>

    <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="Enter your E-mail id"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

   <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:src="@drawable/robo" 
    android:contentDescription="@null"/>

   <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:text="Welcome To Foodparkk"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Login" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

## activity_second.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.firstapp.Second" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check if your button is in `activity_main.xml` or in `fragment_main.xml`..

Comment: Please post the content of the activity_main.xml file. I assume your problem is that you don't have Button field in activity_main.xml

Comment: if that  doesnt solve your problem, try removing `import com.example.firstapp.R;` from your imports

Comment: there is no button with id button_id..instead you have `android:id="@+id/button1"` in your xml file..

Comment: my button is their in activity_main.xml and I added the import com.example.firstapp.R after this error was showing but still the error persists

Comment: yess..you have a button in activity_main.xml...but the id of that button is `button1` and not `button_id`..so change `final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);` to `final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);`

Comment: @LAl-thanx a lot that solved my prob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i mentioned in my comments earlier, There is no button with id `button_id`..
instead you have android:id="@+id/button1" in your xml file..

so, please change

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
```

to

```
final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

in `MainActivity.java`

**OR**

change

```
android:id="@+id/button1"
```

to

```
android:id="@+id/button_id"
```

in your `activity_main.xml`

Comment: but as soon as i click this button a black screen appears and den an error message comes that unfortunately your app has stopped working.Im adding my second activity code also in above code plz check

Comment: my logcat window is showing thousands of messages at a time so couldnt copy them and one more thing,I saw my manifest page,it shows the second xml page on it

Comment: please ask it as a new question..with the manifest,second.java and the layout files..

Answer (score 0):

The button id that you are trying to reference in your Java code (using R.id.button_id) doesn't match the one you declared in your xml file (android:id="@+id/button1"). Try changing it to button1 and the error should go away.

Answer (score 0):

replace `R.id.button_id` with `R.id.button1` since this is what is present in your xml